# MarkLogic SPARQL using property path not returning data as expected

Tags: sparql, marklogic, marklogic-8

Using the following sample triples:

```
@prefix : <http://www.me.org/me_schema#> .
@prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

<http://www.me.org/content/me_schema>
  rdf:type owl:Ontology ;
  owl:imports <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core> ;
.
:a
  rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
  rdfs:label "A" ;
  rdfs:subPropertyOf :b ;
.
:b
  rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
  rdfs:label "B" ;
  rdfs:subPropertyOf :c ;
.
:c
  rdfs:label "C"^^xsd:string ;
.
```

This query returns two rows as expected (both b and c in column ?o):

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select * 
from <test>
where
{
  ?s rdfs:label 'A' .
  ?s rdfs:subPropertyOf+ ?o
}
```

However, I expect the following to return 1 row but it returns empty result. Tested in query console:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select * 
from <test>
where
{
  ?s rdfs:label 'A' .
  ?s rdfs:subPropertyOf+ <http://www.me.org/me_schema#c>
}
```

I expect that it returns one row for "a". Is this a bug or am I missing something obvious?

I tried a similar query with [DBPedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) and it appears to return data as I expected. For example, the following query returns two rows for "star" although neither are direct subClassOf owl:Thing.

```
select *
where 
{
 ?s rdfs:label  "star"@en .
 ?s rdfs:subClassOf+ owl:Thing
} LIMIT 100
```

I came up with the following work around in case anyone is having same problem:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select * 
from <test>
where
{
  ?s rdfs:label 'A' .
  ?s rdfs:subPropertyOf ?s2 .
  ?s2 rdfs:subPropertyOf* <http://www.me.org/me_schema#c>
}
```

Comment: This is useful feedback for the Marklogic team, I'm sure, but what exactly is the question?

Comment: I am relatively new to SPARQL so just want confirmation that I am not missing something stupid.

Comment: Fair enough. To confirm: as far as I can tell you are not missing something, and that second query should indeed have returned 1 result. I ran your example verbatim through another SPARQL engine (Sesame) and got the expected result. So looks like a glitch in MarkLogic. FWIW property paths are one of the trickiest features in the SPARQL spec to get right.

Answer (score 7):

(I would put this in a comment, but I don't have the reputation needed to do that.)

I just tried your null-result example on MarkLogic 8.0-3, and I do indeed get `[{"s":"<http://www.me.org/me_schema#a>"}]`, as you expected. Are you using an earlier version of MarkLogic (you can see the version in the upper-left corner of `localhost:8001`)?

To verify this, I went to the [MarkLogic query console](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/qconsole/walkthru) at `localhost:8000/qconsole/`, set the 'Content Source' to my database (with the triple index turned on) changed the query type to 'SPARQL Update', and entered this SPARQL insert code:

```
PREFIX : <http://www.me.org/me_schema#>
prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

INSERT DATA { GRAPH <test> {
  <http://www.me.org/content/me_schema>  rdf:type owl:Ontology .
  <http://www.me.org/content/me_schema> owl:imports <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core> .

 :a rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .
 :a rdfs:label "A" .
 :a rdfs:subPropertyOf :b .

 :b rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .
 :b rdfs:label "B" .
 :b rdfs:subPropertyOf :c .

 :c rdfs:label "C"^^xsd:string .

  }}
```

I then opened a new tab within the Query Console, set the Query Type to "SPARQL Query", and ran your exact query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select * 
from <test>
where
{
  ?s rdfs:label 'A' .
  ?s rdfs:subPropertyOf+ <http://www.me.org/me_schema#c>
}
```

If you are using an earlier version of MarkLogic, try updating to the latest on the [MarkLogic download page](https://developer.marklogic.com/products).

Comment: There have been fixes to property paths in later versions of MarkLogic 8 - I agree that you should try updating to the latest version.

Comment: I verified that we are on MarkLogic 8.0-3. And I am still getting the null result following the exact same steps as you described above (except the first part is SPARQL Update).

Comment: Does it work if you use `rdfs:subPropertyOf*` instead of `rdfs:subPropertyOf+`? I can't think of why it would be different for you than for me, on the same version of MarkLogic. Maybe try 8.0-4 (the latest)?

Comment: Yes. The problem is with both usage. The strange part with our real data is that the query works for some data but not for other seemly identical data. I could simplify the data to barely minimum and recreate the problem. I am more and more convinced that the problem is in MarkLogic.

Comment: There were a couple small 8.0-3 point releases. On closer examination, I see that I am on 8.0-3.2. This might have been a bug fix on one of those.

Comment: Tried on a different MarkLogic server with version 8.0-3.3 and still observed the same result. I am suspecting that a triple store setting is affecting the outcome but that should really not be the case. Poor performance may be expected with incorrect configuration but the result should always be correct.

Comment: Alex, agreed that configuration shouldn't matter to this query. I can't reproduce the result by tweaking the triple index settings. I could take a look at your other settings if you send me the output of http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/databases/your-database-name-here/properties?format=json ... Also: is this an otherwise empty database, or do you have other documents? Have you set up a default ruleset?